# How can I disable ion-dateTime time selector section?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am making ionic project with angular. I wish to disable and hide the time selector from the `<ion-dateTime>` element. Is it possible? If so what exactly is the syntax? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I find the answer, inside `ion-datetime` element set

```
presentation="date" preferWheel="false"
```

Its in their doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#multiple-date-selection